# Ingame buttons are not clickable

Tags: python, roblox

Im trying to make a script which detects appearing on screen button and click on it. It finds button and setting cursor position to its location but doesnt clicks.

```
    while 1:
        pic1 =  pyautogui.locateOnScreen('pic1.png', confidence=0.8)
        if pic1:
            x, y = pyautogui.center(pic1)
            pydirectinput.click(x,y)
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
```

I tried lots ways of clicking like Win32api, Mouse, directinput, autogui and ahk libs but still nothing. Is there any other ways to try for clicking the button?

Comment: You have added the 'roblox' tag, although it is seemly unrelated to Roblox. Can you elaborate why you think the 'roblox' tag fits the question?